# LESS formatter for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, less

I usually work with SCSS. However, now I have to work with LESS and the extension I use to format SCSS doesnt work with LESS. I would like to ask you, whether you can help me to find good formatter extension for Visual Studio Code or help me to set options in the right way. The best would be if it works with `.editorconfig` file.

For example, I tried this one: https://github.com/tierratelematics/code-beautifier with such VSCode settings:

```
// Tab options
  "beautify.options": {
    "indent_size": 2,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "indent_with_tabs": false,
    "selector-separator-newline": true,
    "newline-between-rules": true
  },
// Tab Size
  "beautify.tabSize": 2,
```

`beautify.tabSize` works but nothing else have an effect.

Or would you rather recommend me to use this big format extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify for all HTML, JS? Even it doesn't say it supports LESS files, I still believe it can work with LESS?

I'm curious about your experience. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shinnn.stylelint

Comment: Thanks. However, Im not looking for linter but formatter.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```js
"beautify.options": {
    "css": {
        "newline_between_rules": true,
        "end_with_newline": true,
    },
},
```

and some config may not valid for wrapped LESS. (eg. newline_between_rules).

Need restart VSCode after edit the config.

And also **Style formatter**: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dweber019.vscode-style-formatter